# Normed vector space (Topology)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology

**Show that if a subspace** $F$ **of a normed vector space E is opened then** $F = E$

My hint is to use the fact that $0_{E}\in F$ wich means that it exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B(0_{E}, \varepsilon)\subset F$ and thus show that $B(0_{E}, \varepsilon)$ is absorbant. Is it enough to say that $E=F$? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First case:** $E$ is finite-dimensional with orthonormal basis $\{u_1,\dots, u_n\}$. Then since there exists, as you pointed out, $\epsilon > 0$ such that $D(0_{E}, \epsilon) \subset F$, then $\{\frac{\epsilon}{2}u_1, \dots \frac{\epsilon}{2}u_n \} \subset F$, therefore $\dim F = n$, which yields $F=E$.

**Second case:** $E$ is infinite-dimensional. Let $u \in E$, then $\frac{\epsilon}{2||u||}u \in D(0_{E}, \epsilon) \subset F$, therefore yielding that $u \in F$ as $F$ is a subspace (therefore if $a \in F$, then $\lambda a \in F$ for every $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$). In fact, you don't need the first case scenario, but I think it shows you with $F = E$, in the sense that *all the dimensions are contained in F*

Comment: Thank you for that clarification @Hermès

Comment: I think that in the case  where $F$ is closed the result is the same?

Comment: @KARMA If $F$ is closed, then we do not have necessarily that $F = E$. In fact, any finite-dimensional subspace $F \in E$ with $E$ normed space in closed.

Comment: Ok, that's interesting @Hermès